# SSIS Excel Source wiping out IMEX=1 setting in Excel Connection Manager (ACE 12). Any way around this?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, visual-studio-2019, ms-jet-ace

ACE engine and SSIS woes in VS2019. I want to stop incorrectly typed data from just disappearing because ACE makes it NULL. Once the data is in SSIS, I will type the data using Data Conversion and deal with any bad data at that point. The solution to ACE losing data is of course to set IMEX=1 and to include the header row in the data (to provide guaranteed string data) and then use a WHERE clause to exclude the header row. This will set all columns to string in ACE and therefore SHOULD set all Excel Source external columns to string - unfortunately it doesn't.

The problem:

Create an Excel Connection Manager. Don't set the header checkbox. There is no option to set IMEX.
Then manually add IMEX=1 to the ConnectionString. This works and you can see it has been added.
Create an Excel Source. Select the Excel Connection Manager. Write a SELECT statement to get your data. Unfortunately, preview shows the bad data has been set to NULL and that the IMEX=1 setting has been removed from the Excel Connection Manager.

Did this always happen as I've seen quite a few old solutions that suggest manually adding IMEX=1 and this suggests that it used to work, so is this a regression in recent versions?

Incidentally, once you have linked an Excel Source to the Excel Connection Manager, the Connectionstring of the manager is no longer editable. You can edit it again if you remove the link.

You can add IMEX=1 to the dynamic Expression ConnectionString, but this is not useful at design time when setting up the column datatypes.

One workaround is to add string data to at least 5 of the top 8 rows for the design time Excel file (so when ACE guesses the column datatype it chooses string even without IMEX=1). But it's really hacky and any maintenance developer coming in will likely break the datatypes.

Comment: I've read things that say that Preview is different to actual import. Have you tested actually impotring into a table? I can't believe this is still a problem with ACE after all these years it's crazy.

Comment: I wrote a clone of SSMS just to avoid dealing with the excel import "wizard". I'm amazed that dealing with files is still the biggest hurdle when working with sql server, ever since 2000

Comment: Let's get down to a reproducible sample. If Excel looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgAa1.png this, it interprets column A and B as unicode strings. The preview shows NULL for the blank values. I can import it but I want to make sure I understand the specifics of what your sheet looks like, the interpreted data types, the conversions you apply and how you have things set up. Edit your question, throw out some screenshots and let's dig into the atrocious world of Excel data storage

Comment: Nick.McDermaid - Preview and design time are the same. Runtime can be different, but my issue is with design time only. billinkc - the link doesn't work (i.stack.imgur.com uses an unsupported protocol. ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH in Chrome and Edge). The SQL Command in the Excel Source is similar to: SELECT F1 AS MemberId,
       F2 AS SchemeId,
       F3 AS SchemeName,
       F5 AS DateOfExtract
FROM [Sheet 1$A9:BX]
WHERE F2 <> 'ID'
where row 9 is the header row. As already mentioned, when IMEX=1 is set in the connection manager, it gets removed as soon as the source is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I'm an idiot. When you add Expressions they override the attribute that they cover AT DESIGN TIME AND RUN TIME. The properties window will update from the expression once the changes are saved. For some reason I thought the underlying property was used at design time and the expression was just used at runtime. I can't believe how long it has taken me to come to this simple conclusion. Anyway, apologies again for being a moron. I'll leave this up in case anyone else is having a funny 5 minutes.

So, basically, change the expression and save and it will change the underlying property value.